# MassTransit publish to specific queue

Tags: masstransit

I have successfully updated a MassTransit app from 2.x to 3.x and switched to RabbitMQ for my transport.  I did this to get one-to-many messaging to function properly, which the previous developer thought would work with MSMQ but I found it was not working and it became clear by reading the documentation that I would need to use 3.x and RabbitMQ.

My application has multiple instances of a website running on the server, with each instance for a specific customer base.  I want each instance to publish to specific queues so that the data is only available to the back-end processes for the particular instance.  I can easily configure each of these processes to only read from specific queues, but how do I get MassTransit to publish only to specific queues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably configure a separate RabbitMQ virtual host for each customer, and point that customer's web site instance to that specific virtual host. That way, each way site has its own virtual service for message traffic, keeping it isolated from the other.

Comment: Thanks Chris!  Exactly what I was looking for.